# How to change the @title.visible to false in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

this is a betting game that flips the shown image card when the card button is clicked. i want the website to change/flip the tile images when the card button is clicked.  How can I change the Visibility to true when I run the first loop of code(since i hv to loop the code 2 times to flip the card)

my code is

```
 @foreach (var tile in Model)
    {
        <div style="width: 400px;">
            <div class="card" style="width: 100px; float:left;">

                @if (tile.Visible == false)
                {
                    <img src="~/images/unknown.png" alt="..." style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">                    
                    <input asp-action="Index" type="submit" value="Choose" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="@tile.Visible = true;"/>
                }
                else if (tile.Visible == true) //show the tile value
                {
                    <img src="~/images/bust.png" alt="..." style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
                    if (tile.Value == "0.00")
                    {

                        //substract the bet coins from number of coins if lost
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        //increase the number of coins if won
                    }
                    <input asp-controller="Game" asp-action="betCoins" type="submit" value="Choose" class="btn btn-primary" />

                }

                <br>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div>@tile.Value</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically when you dealing with set of objects define a unique property to identify each item in the collection. Usually this property used as a key when mapped to the database table. When it's necessary to perform some operations on the object, it is enough to call the controller's method and pass only the object identifier and not the object itself.

Suppose is defined the following data model:

```cs
public class DataObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool Visible { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
List<DataObject> model= ... // Obtain data from repository

public ActionResult Index()
{   
    return View(model);
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Choose(int tileId)
{
    var item = model.Where(i => i.Id == tileId).SingleOrDefault();
    item.Visible = true;
    return View("Index", model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult betCoins(int tileId)
{
    var item = model.Where(i => i.Id == tileId).SingleOrDefault();
    item.Visible = false;
    return View("Index", model);
}
```

The `Index.cshtml`:

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.DataObject>

@foreach (var tile in Model)
{ 
<div style="width: 400px;">
    <div class="card" style="width: 100px; float:left;">

        @if (tile.Visible == false)
        {
            <img src="~/images/unknown.png" alt="..." style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">            

            using (Html.BeginForm("Choose", "Game", new { tileId = tile.Id }))
            {                
                <input type="submit" value="Choose" />
            }
        }
        else if (tile.Visible == true) //show the tile value
        {
            <img src="~/images/bust.png" alt="..." style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">

            if (tile.Value == "0.00")
            {
                //substract the bet coins from number of coins if lost
            }
            else
            {
                //increase the number of coins if won
            }
            using (Html.BeginForm("BetCoins", "Game", new { tileId = tile.Id }))
            {
                <input type="submit" value="Choose" />
            }         
        }
        <br>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div>@tile.Value</div>
        </div>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
}
```